# REST API design best practices for resources that can also belong to other resources

Tags: rest, api, http, asp.net-web-api

For the sake of simplicity let's say that I have an API to manage projects, each project can have milestones. Milestones belong to a project, but I should also be able to retrieve a list of all milestones (for example to display in a dashboard)

What is the most appropriate way to set up my routes so that I can get milestones in general as well as ones specifically for a given project?

```
GET /api/project/{id}/milestones/
```

or

```
GET /api/milestones/?projectId=123
```

Or a completely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

The correct naming, according to the standards/best practices is this one:

```
GET /api/projects/{idProject}/milestones/
```

notice the plural `projects`. That's the first voice to mention, and it is used to clearly specify the topic which the api treats. Then you specify `idProject` to select a particular project. And finally you navigate to a `sub-collection` resource of the project, `milestones`.

If you want further reference you can find it [here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/).

PS: The `/api` is pretty general/common prefix of rest resources. It can be omitted in some cases, it is a matter of choice. It doesn't really have some specfic meaning in the context.

Comment: ReST says to treat URLs as opaque. There is exactly zero guidance in ReST as to what URLs should look like. Your reference incorrectly claims otherwise.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is not a *strong* reference but rather a set of rules/best practices to follow.

Comment: I don't know who "most of us" is. I do know that the document you claim is a set of best practices misunderstands ReST from the title onward. That's enough for me to discount it as a reasonable source of information. :)

Comment: So I don't understand you. Did you downvote the answer because it is wrong or just because the attached reference is incorrect (at least in some parts) according to you?

Comment: The missing "s" was just a typo :). My question was more about what is considered the best route to use to get milestones for a given project knowing that I can also get a list of ALL milestones via GET /api/milestones/

I'm leaning towards GET /api/milestones/?projectId=123 because it presents a more cohesive set of URLs to manage milestone resources.

Comment: How can you even say that there are standards/best practices when all you have is a link to restfulapi.net, you can't validate that website more than any other so to say that it's the source of standards or best practice is madness. And the /api/ url is a none-sense as well.

Comment: @matt_lethargic First of all you should moderate your language, that tone is not acceptable in this website. Afterwards you can agree or not with someones idea but you should express your agreement or disagreement in a contained way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, from my experiences, you are spot on with both

```
GET /api/projects/{id}/milestones/
GET /api/milestones/?projectId=123
```

Neither is right or wrong, which one you use or indeed if you need both will come from requirements of the project or personal taste.

The second one I would personally use as a milestone search endpoint if I wanted to search for milestones across different projects or different params eg:

```
GET /api/milestones/?userId=bob
GET /api/milestones/?createdDate=20180101
```

The first url I would just to just get back milestones for that project and then if required add filters from there.

Again personal taste / project requirments